# Create a wav with hidden binary data in it and read it (Java)

Tags: java, text, audio, signal-processing, wav

What I'm willing to do is to convert a text string into a wav file format in high frequencies (18500Hz +): this will be the encoder.
And create an engine to decode this text string from a wav formatted recording that will support error control as I will not use the same file obviously, to read, but a recording of this sound.

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question ? Which part are you having difficulty with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important consideration will be whether or not you want to hide the string into an existing audio file (so it sounds like a normal file, but has an encoded message -- that is called [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)), or whether you will just be creating a file that sounds like gibberish, for the purpose of encoding data only. I'm assuming the latter since you didn't ask to hide a message in an existing file.

So I assume you are not looking for low-level details on writing WAV files (I am sure you can find documentation on how to read and write individual samples to a WAV file). Obviously, the simplest approach would be to simply take each byte of the source string, and store it as a sample in the WAV file (assuming an 8-bit recording. If it's a 16-bit recording, you can store two bytes per sample. If it's a stereo 16-bit recording, you can store four bytes per sample). Then you can just read the WAV file back in and read the samples back as bytes. That's the simple approach but as you say, you want to be able to make a (presumably analog) recording of the sound, and then read it back into a WAV file, and still be able to read the data.

With the approach above, if the analog recording is not exactly perfect (and how could it be), you would lose bytes of the message. This means you need to store the message in such a way that missing bytes, or bytes that have a slight error, are not going to be a problem. How you do this will depend highly upon exactly what sort of "damage" will be happening to the sound file. I would expect two major forms of damage:

- "Vertical" damage: A sample (byte) would have a slightly higher or lower value than it originally had.
- "Horizontal" damage: Samples may be averaged, stretched or squashed horizontally. From a byte perspective, this means some samples may be repeated, while others may be missing.

To combat this, you need some redundancy in the message. More redundancy means the message will take up more space (be longer), but will be more reliable.

I would recommend thinking about how old (pre-mobile) telephone dial tones worked: each key generated a unique tone and sent it across the wire. The tones are long enough, and far enough apart pitch-wise that they can be distinguished even given the above forms of damage. So, choose two parameters: a) *length* and b) *frequency-delta*. For each byte of data, select a frequency, spacing the 256 byte values *frequency-delta* Hertz apart. Then, generate a sine wave for *length* milliseconds of that frequency. This encodes a lot more redundancy than the above one-byte-per-sample approach, since each byte takes up many samples, and if you lose some samples, it doesn't matter.

When you read them back in, read every *length* milliseconds of audio data and then estimate the frequency of the sine wave. Map this onto the byte value with the nearest frequency.

Obviously, longer values of *length* and further-apart *frequency-delta* will make the signal more reliable, but require the sound to be longer and higher-frequency, respectively. So you will have to play around with these values to see what works.

Some last thoughts, since your title says "hidden" binary data:

- If you really want the data to be "hidden", consider encrypting it before encoding it to audio.
- If you want to take the steganography approach, you will have to read up on audio steganography (I imagine you can use the above techniques, but you will have to insert them as extremely low-volume signals on top of the existing sound).

Comment: I've tried successfully to give each character it's own frequency so I could then listen for that frequency and display the message again.
Problem is, I'm using FFT (Fast Fourier transform) in order to represent the spectrum of frequencies and then read the message according to dominant frequencies. But FFT prevents me from retrieving the strength of the actual frequency as it's "accurate" for about 43hz which isn't enough for me.
What can I use instead or with FFT in order to get greater accuracy?

Comment: As far as I know, the FFT is the way you determine the frequency of a wave. What do you mean its inaccurate? Is this from your experiments? Have you tried running it on the pure WAV file without the analog-to-digital-to-analog conversion? I wouldn't expect it to be inaccurate. If you make the length of each byte longer, does that increase accuracy?

Comment: What I get as an output from FFT is the strength of a frequency for a given framesize, and the "skipping" between frequencies is 43 hz as I wrote earlier.
I have experimented this, by creating wavs for each byte and appending them together to make a message.
When reading, soem bytes pick up quickly and some don't, I think I figured out why and thats because It picks up neighbor frequencies as the strongest frequency. (As i'm not getting 1hz accuracy but 43hz).
I need a way to get the strength of a frequency in a greater accuracy than 43hz.

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced -- I haven't actually written any FFT code. But what library are you using? From what I've seen, FFTs give you continuous (or close enough to it) analysis of the strength of all frequencies. If you are only able to measure the strength of every 43Hz, then perhaps you are using the wrong library.